# How to send a job to a printer or print server from a web API service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, printing

I have a project where, in some corporate setting, I need to keep track of a set of printers and sent print jobs to different servers, and have clients contact a server that will then generate a print job on a specific server.

the `System.printing` namespace comes with a big asterisk that it shouldn't be used on ASP.net or on a service. What should I use instead?

Comment: Try using GetPrintQueues : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue.name?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @jdweng "Classes within the System.Printing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows service or ASP.NET application or service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions."

Comment: What user would be used when printing?  The service doesn't have the users credentials.  the service is running with the account that started the service.  See : https://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/remote-printing-with-asp-net-web-api-in-windows-service/

Comment: If using Windows Authentication the service knows who the user is. But even if using no authentication, the account that started the service can be granted rights to print.